# Animation Repeat Count didn't work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I create an animation i swift, and defined the repeat count to 1. I was expecting that the animation will play once and then stop. But when i build the app the animation didn't even play. Its a static image.

That's my code:

```
func animarPredios() {
    self.animationImages = nil
    self.image = UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios10.png")


    self.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios1.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios2.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios3.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios4.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios5.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios6.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios7.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios8.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios9.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "tutorial_predios10.png")!
        ]

    self.animationDuration = 6
    self.animationRepeatCount = 1
    self.startAnimating()

    }
```

What i did wrong?

Comment: What does `self.startAnimating()` do?

Comment: starts the animation

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Did you subclass from `UIActivityIndicatorView`? If not, please show us what you have done in `startAnimating` method.

Comment: I create a swift file, and initialize it with:

"class PrediosTutorial: UIImageView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        animarPredios()
    }
Then i go to the image that i want to animate and changed the class in the identity inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state you call `animarPredios` in `viewDidLoad`. That is too soon. The animation is complete before the view even appears. Call it in `viewDidAppear:`. Then you will see the one animation.

Comment: Hi, @rmaddy, it worked. But when i run the app, before start the animation, the last image of the animation appears and then go. After that, the animation starts. Do you know what might be?

Comment: It's probably a slight delay in the animation starting. You could try calling `animarPredios` from `viewWillAppear:` but then you might not see the 1st image or two.